# Justifying references with footfullcit - Beamer

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

Per default `biblatex` has all their references justified in case they overflow the first line, at least with `cite`, for some reason in the `beamer` class using the Metropolis theme and citing with `\footfullcite` I don't get this behavior.

Thought it would be the same behavior with footcites but apparently it isn't so.

Tried googling but couldn't find an answer on how to justify foot cites. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Trial Slide}
Text \footfullcite{sigfridsson}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit: To add my confusion that footcites would have the same behavior thant cites

Comment: Oh, I had never used footcites before, at least with normal cites it justifies it, thought it would be the same behavior with footcites. I couldn't find any information on the links you provided on how to justify them.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question then, sorry. `biblatex` itself does not apply any sort of justification to its citation output. Neither `\cite` nor `\footcite` or `\footfullcite` do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike other documentclasses, beamer does not justify any text because it is made for short text elements, which will often look odd if justified.

To add justification to the footnote, you could redefine the `footnote` template:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\justifying\insertfootnotetext\par%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Trial Slide}
Text \footfullcite{sigfridsson}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works, and it's just what I needed!

Comment: @M.O. You're welcome!